# How to load extensions

Tags: vulkan, mesa

I am trying to write a Vulkan program but am somewhat fuzzy on how the extension mechanism works.

Concretely, I want to access `VK_COLOR_SPACE_EXTENDED_SRGB_NONLINEAR_EXT` (is not found at compilation) but am not sure how to include the swapchain_colorspace extension.

Comment: Is there a problem using the Vulkan SDK? Does it not come with extension loading built-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VK_EXT_swapchain_colorspace` is an **instance** extension.
You can enable the extension by passing its name to `vkCreateInstance` via the `pCreateInfo->ppEnabledExtensionNames`.

You can use either `"VK_EXT_swapchain_colorspace"` directly or use the `VK_EXT_SWAPCHAIN_COLOR_SPACE_EXTENSION_NAME` macro to avoid typos.

Then, generally speaking, you have to load extension commands (functions) unless it is WSI and you are using the official Vulkan loader.
`VK_EXT_swapchain_colorspace` defines no new commands, so that step can be skipped.

Enumerants such as `VK_COLOR_SPACE_EXTENDED_SRGB_NONLINEAR_EXT` are always present\defined (assuming you have updated `vulkan.h` header; if not, just download newest [LunarG Vulkan SDK](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home)). Enabling the extension only gives formal permission for them to be used.

Comment: Just include the usual vulkan.h header.